# django refuses to recognize static folder?

Tags: django, mezzanine

UPDATE - it is reading the static folder correctly.  If I make a test.css file and then try to go to `http://myserver:8000/static/css/test.css` it will pick it up.

The problem is when i try to put a new bootstrap.css into that folder.  It ignores that I have a custom one and instead uses the one that is in the python2.7/dist/mezzanine/.... folder.  The templates don't have this issue when I collected them.  base.html is custom and it uses mine and not the default stored copy so why isn't it doing this with the static files?

I've tried many different stackoverflow and google examples but it would seem out of the box my django/mezzanine app doesn't want to recognize the static files I'm using.

My static files are located in '/opt/myproject/static/'

settings.py

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))
STATIC_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),)
```

I'll note that even hardcoding the path doesn't help -

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/opt/myproject/static/"
STATIC_DIRS = ("/opt/myproject/static",)
```

The base.html is the Mezzanine default so here is how it's looking for the static files -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}">
```

If I hardcode the location to the css there it won't find the file -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/opt/myproject/static/css/bootstrap.css">
```

I'm at a loss as to why it's not picking up the static files anywhere but the mezzanine home folder.  If I do a findstatic it never finds my folder only the default -

```
python manage.py findstatic css/bootstrap.css
Found 'css/bootstrap.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mezzanine/core/static/css/bootstrap.css
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit to include that I have DEBUG = True

I've done the urls.py trick -

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I've also done python manage.py runserver --unsecure

Comment: try `STATIC_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static/"),)` and `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static/")` note the trailing slash

Comment: No idea how that's possible. Try temporarily removing the `mezzanine/core/static/css/bootstrap.css` and see if it falls back on your custom one

Comment: @Ben - This is so weird.  I renamed it to bootstrap.old and yes, then it picks up my custom bootstrap.css in my projects static folder.  and it gets weirder.  If I rename it back it's keeping my custom css.  something is caching somewhere and it's not releasing it is all I can think of.

Comment: bizarre.. try and fire up a new project at some point, see if it has the same symptoms. That, or consult a ouija board I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `./manage.py collectstatic` this should pull up all your new static files. This will also tell you if your STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL is set correctly or not.

Comment: collectstatic works fine and copies over all the files but it still is not recognizing my changed files.

Comment: Are you deploying your project in a production environment or is this just dev?

Comment: update here that the problem was it wasn't production.  I have one environment productionalized using mod_wsgi and the static files are correct.  development environment this is an issue so effectively I can't test in development...